# unable to store array's multiple values in one single insert query in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, html

Edited:
In my application I want to store two array value in a two column with a single query. I am stuck here.Last two column value insert is my problem.I tried many ways but it's does not work exactly what i want. [image: New db design]

in database that question id is same only other two things r different. My array values goes to the last column of database. I am unable to do that.

**from here data goes**

```
<form method="post" action="questionmadddb.php">
<input name='questionid' value='<?php echo $questionid?> 
<?php
if(isset($_POST['num'])){
    $num=$_POST['num'];
    for ($i=1; $i <=$num ; $i++) { 
        echo "<tr>
        <td><label>OPTION " . $i . "</label></td>
        <td><input class='form-control' name='txtfllname[]'></td>
        <td><input class='form-control' name='txtflrname[]'></td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
?>
<td colspan=6><button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" >ADD QUESTION</button></td>
```

**here is query**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["txtfllname"]) && is_array($_POST["txtfllname"])){ 
$capture_field_vals ="";
foreach($_POST["txtfllname"] as $key => $text_field){
    $a=("INSERT INTO qflinfo (questionid,qfllid,qfllname,qflrid,qflrname,status) VALUES ('$questionid','$i','$text_field',0)");
    $i++;
    //echo $a;
    mysqli_query($conn,$a) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}

}?>
```

how to get last two column data and insert?please help me...How can I do that?

Comment: can you post the complete log error rather, with line number ?

Comment: please change name of  either `$value=array();` or `foreach ($_POST['txtoptname'] as $value) {`  , you have used `$value` twice

Comment: please check my edited code and question.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST["txtfllname"]) && is_array($_POST["txtfllname"])){ 
$capture_field_vals ="";

foreach($_POST["txtfllname"] as $key => $text_field){

    if($key>=count($_POST["txtfllname"])-2)
    {
        $a=("INSERT INTO qflinfo (questionid,qfllid,qfllname,qflrid,qflrname,status) VALUES ('$questionid','$i','$text_field',0)");
        $i++;

        mysqli_query($conn,$a) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }

}

}?>
```

Comment: @ArpanSarkar "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings" this error resolved as per your question.

Comment: this is my edited question.tell me how to insert txtflrname.

Comment: <?php

if(isset($_POST["txtfllname"]) && is_array($_POST["txtfllname"])){ 
$capture_field_vals ="";

foreach($_POST["txtfllname"] as $key => $text_field){

    if($key>=count($_POST["txtfllname"])-2)
    {
        $a=("INSERT INTO qflinfo (questionid,qfllid,qfllname,qflrid,qflrname,status) VALUES ('$questionid','$i','$text_field',0)");
        $i++;

        mysqli_query($conn,$a) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }

}

}?>

Answer (score 0):

You redeclare $value in your for-loop. Rename either
**$value**=array();
or
$_POST['txtoptname'] as **$value**